# WSO2 IS - How to infer the parameter names in deployment.toml

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I need to add several parameter values from some configuration files to the deployment file deployment.toml in WSO2 IS 5.9.0. I fail to infer the proper name so that the IS load them properly. How can I infer how to build the parameter names in that file? Any rules?

Cheers

Comment: can you add  the configuration files that you are going to add these new parameters and what are these parameters

Comment: I need the name for the parameter <filterusersandgroupsonlyfromprimarydomain> in identity.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the following to

   > IS_HOME/repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/identity.xml.j2 file

```html
    <filterusersandgroupsonlyfromprimarydomain>{{filter.onlyfromprimary.enable}}</filterusersandgroupsonlyfromprimarydomain>
```

2. Add the following to IS_HOME/repository/conf/default.json

> "filter.onlyfromprimary.enable": true

This will be the default value

3. Change the configuration as per your requirement from

> IS_HOME/repository/conf/deployment.toml

```
[filter.onlyfromprimary]
enable = true
```

Here I have assumed this value is a boolean as you havent provided that information. You can change as per your requirement. Also, ***filter.onlyfromprimary.enable*** this key value also can be changed as per your requirement. Please refer[1] for more information

[1]. https://medium.com/@madurangasaneth/simplified-centralized-configuration-model-in-wso2-is-5-9-0-onward-b149b878a695